# Zip_choropleth only one color gradient in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

So I am trying to use the Zip_Choropleth in R to develop a country wide zipcode map.

My data is at the zip level and I manage to get the data to render.

[image: US MAP of Digital Media Impressions]

However , I only get one distribution. I tried setting `min`s and `max`s of the data

```
Data[(Data$value > 100000),'value'] <- 100000
Data[(Data$value < 1000),'value'] <- 0
```

but it still does not provide any even distributions, the code to plot is as follows:

```
zip_choropleth(Data, 
           title  = " Exposures - 2015 H1",
           legend = "Impressions" , 
           num_colors= 9 
           )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the `zip_choropleth` function? It's not in `ggplot2`...

Comment: Hi the function is in choroplethrZip package but i believe ggplot2 can be used for some of the functionality here.

Answer (score 0):

for num_colors, use 1. That sets it as a continuous scale.